# Simple self-hosted website monitoring

Tags: web, hosting, monitoring, self-hosting

I'm looking for a simple self hosted website monitoring tool.
It should be somthing similar to watchmouse.com or pimgdom.com, with a nice UI, colorful charts and so on (Customers like that :)).
At the moment we use Zabbix also for HTTP monitoring, but since now our hoster care about the hardware and software monitoring on the machine directly, we don't need Zabbix anymore.
For pure http-monitoring zabbix or an other monitoring suite is really an overkill.

So what I'm not looking for is:

- Zabbix
- Nagios
- Hyperic
- ...

Sadly but the truth, after some hours of researching I wasn't able to find a fitting application. My hope is now on you.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question but I was looking for something like this today and came across [Cabot](https://github.com/arachnys/cabot/) which is self hosted and free, and according to the project's description: "provides some of the best features of PagerDuty, Server Density, Pingdom and Nagios".

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I found this a while ago for my purposes. Nice and simple and self hosted.
You do need shell access to setup cron jobs for it so it probably won't work in a shared environment.
[php Server Monitor](http://docs.phpservermonitor.org/en/latest/intro.html)

Hope this helps.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of success with [Groundwork](http://www.gwos.com/) in the past, It's a BEAST and does just about everything imaginable and can be configured in so many ways. It might be overkill if you are just looking for something to schedule some http responses then graph the logs.

Groundwork is more for enterprise level deployments and has both Paid and Community editions with a pretty active community behind it too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have already found a solution to this or not but give a shot to [Apica System](https://www.apicasystem.com/monitoring/)'s Synthetic Monitoring. You can use the full SaaS, full on-premise, or hybrid model of this system. Take a look at the free trial and if you like what you see, the full portal as well as monitoring agents (with tons of more features than the trial) can be hosted behind your firewall in your own network. As per for monitoring, you can monitor websites/mobile apps, API endpoints, DNS, etc. You can also run complex use cases and see how the web app responds using Selenium or ZebraTester scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to monitor is website uptime/downtime and response time, I'd have a look at [TurboMonitor](http://www.turbomonitor.com/) - it doesn't have all the bells and whistles provided by some other monitoring websites but it's quick and accurate for those two things.

Price-wise, I wouldn't take what they have on their website too seriously. I only actually found out about them when I met them in person and they were very happy to give me a "professional" account for free, supposedly like 5€/month or something on their website.

Comment: This is not self-hosted